# Buttons are being distorted after changing minSdkVersion in the manifest

Tags: android

The buttons are being distorted after changing minSdkVersion in the manifest from 10 to 11. If I change it back to 10 the buttons are fine. These buttons all have respective drawables in each of the drawable folders. This is happening to buttons without drawables as well. Buttons that just have text the text gets enlarged quite a bit.

[image: Normal buttons]

[image: Distorted buttons]

Edit to add xml example:

Here is what the  button in xml looks like.

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/settingsEditInfoBtn"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/edit_info_btn" />
```

The text is part of the image. Here is the edit info button drawable.

[image: Edit info drawable]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The minHeight and minWidth of buttons are being set by the default theme somewhere. Setting them both to 1dp solved the problem in this case.

```
<Button
  android:id="@+id/settingsEditInfoBtn"
  android:minHeight="1dp"
  android:minWidth="1dp"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="@drawable/edit_info_btn" />
```

Or you can set a button style in your application theme that overrides these values for all buttons. In the values/themes.xml:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme">
  <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/MyButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
  <item name="android:minHeight">1dp</item>
  <item name="android:minWidth">1dp</item>
</style>
```

Then, don't forget to apply the custom theme to any desired activities in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
  android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
</activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is normal. The default font/size/style varies between the two API levels and the text is rendered in the default font corresponding to the API level. By definition the app inherits the default Holographic theme when you set min/Targets Sdk Version to 11 or greater.

If you want to have the size of your choice you should explicitly define your style and use it in your layout.

```
<style name="CustomTheme">
<item name="textSize"> 14dp </item>
</style>
```

and use it in your button.

```
<Button style="@style/CustomTheme"
android:layout_width=".." 
../>
```

Comment: Well, that affects the text size of buttons that have text, but what you described has no affect on buttons that don't have text. The buttons in the images I posted do not have their text property set to anything, rather the text is part of the background drawable. So changing the text size does not make a difference. The buttons are still stretched.

Comment: Fair enough. The default padding and  margins of buttons may vary according to the API levels.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction with the theme. It seems the minHeight and minWidth of buttons are being set by the default theme somewhere. Using a custom theme like you suggested could solve the issue now that I know what attributes are causing the problem.